# Azure 2.5 SDK Upgrade Causes CSPack Fail

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-sdk-.net, cspack

I just upgraded to Azure SDK Tools 2.5 in Visual Studio 2012 and when I try to publish via the GUI to Azure I am getting the following error during the final CSPack step.

ERROR MESSAGE:

The "CSPack" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' in Assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

I understand what the error is offering, but cannot figure out what is causing this to fail...as previous version of the SDK Tools had no issues with this reference.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Jason, sorry for the trouble you are experiencing with CSPack. Could you let me know if you are using any RoleInstanceValue with XPath queries in your .csdef file? Is there any place in your Cloud Service project where the type XElement is used?

Comment: Same problem after upgrade from 2.2 to 2.5

Comment: @WayneKuo, is it something you are going to fix in 2.6 SDK?

Comment: @Maxim Alexeyev, this is already fixed in 2.5.1. The same fix will be in 2.6

Answer (score 3):

Although I do not know the root cause. I found a workaround after upgrade to Azure SDK 2.5:

Copy the Azure SDK 2.4 version cspack.exe, ServiceDescription.dll & Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MsBuildTasks.dll to Azure SDK 2.5 cspack.exe location and replace. This would using cspack 2.4 to pack with Azure SDK 2.5 runtimes.

Verified the package deployment in Azure without problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately it does not fulfil the requirement of my bounty for not manipulating with windows Azure SDK, but from all answers provided, this seems be best of bads solution. Personally I prefer to have solution I could use on any computer, where I work with source codes, without effort. In my case I rather selected downgrade project to 2.4, which is also very painful task :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Per dev team, this is a bug in 2.5 version of tools.
It will be fixed in 2.5.1 version which is currently expected to be available before end of this month (March).

Comment: Update: fix is available now

Comment: Notice that if you have an existing Azure-project in your solution, you would have to update the Azure-project to use the new version. Right-cklick the Azure-project in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer panel, choose Properties and go to the Application tab to verify that you use Azure SDK 2.5.1 or later, or upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is now fixed in the latest Azure SDK 2.5.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Decided to roll back SDK 2.5 and return to 2.4. This is not the only issue. Nothing works as usual, Server explorer Azure tools don't work too. I was disconnected, then i had to remove my account and add it again in order to see the storage accounts. But that didn't fix the issues or doing any work on the storage objects like tables for example.

Uninstall of Azure SDK 2.5 is not required. Just revert the upgrade of the VS projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error when loading a VS 2013 solution with multiple Azure "webrole" projects after updating to Azure 2.5 from 2.4. I was also not able to see anything currently deployed on Azure from with Server Tools. I decided to reboot my dev machine and the errors went away when loading the solution and I was again able to browse Azure server. I also was able to rebuild the entire solution without any issues but I have not yet tried to deploy to Azure from VS 2013 yet.